# Can I work remotely while being a tourist in Russia?

Tags: russia, work

I have for many years now, spent most of my days, answering online surveys.  They pay usually up to £1.00 or so each, and I do them online.  Next week I'm going to Russia on a Tourism visa.  Can I legally continue to answer the surveys while I am there?  My application is as unemployed, because predominantly I am.  The surveys take up my whole days, usually, and mostly only pay every few out every few months.

Comment: As long as the 'consumer' of those surveys isn't based in Russia, you're OK.

Comment: I think while logically it looks like work, no Russian will consider it as work by this description. "You do *what*? Stop bothering me."

Comment: I m curious: which website pays up to £1 per survey?

Comment: @Ulkoma some do; [this Telegraph article outlined those that pay](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/personalfinance/money-saving-tips/11042019/Five-minute-guide-to-making-easy-money-with-online-surveys.html)

Comment: Ulkoma there are many.  Some offer and pay much more respectively.  You can apply for focus groups also, which pay typically £40-60 or so fir 1-2 hours in person or online.  Applications have tasks that pay up to £15 from memory.  It mostly depends on which country you live in.  Upon seeing your living in Britain, there are numerous survey sites.  As examples, Toluna, valued opinions, GlobalTestMarket, youGov and MindMover.  There are varied values to every survey and it's a roundabout survey.  Most surveys pay if you qualify from 0.05

Comment: Gayot, often it's impossible to avoid and determine the subjects.   For example on apple, or Samsung. Or on what technology and products you own, politics, and international societal behaviours.  I know that you mean that you think Russia doesn't want to be affected, but they're not the sole occupants on the planet.

Comment: Alamar, good, but some here disagree and it might be futile to question.  I hope it doesn't matter and would rather be sure.

Comment: Dorothy,I'm registered with all of those and all except possibly 1-2 haven't paid me sometime.  Do not be bargained for though on the higher rewards promised like £5-10. No, no, and they often say that and very rarely indeed if at all d it.They're mostly up to £2 at best.  Other websites do offer more, that uk citizens can do including in USA survey sites and they'll mostly pay you in their currency.   The good thing is that they often ask you at the end if you'd be interested in taking part in further (or bigger) research which can lead you to a focus group, or something different.

Answer (score 6):

This question comes up all the time. Two things

1. Tax wise you are not working in Russia. You are paying your taxes in the UK.
2. Theoretically, the FSB or whatever can spy on you to find out what you are doing online. In practice there are like 35 million tourists a year in Russia. I will let you guess whether they do.

This sort of work we digital nomads do is not well regulated and falls through the cracks. Who will know whether you are filling out a fun quiz (which, by the way, if connected to Facebook, will just expand the profile of what advertisers know about you and you'll be surprised how much personality can be learned from favorite movies but I digress) or getting paid for it.

We usually do not encourage breaking the law on this site but the definition is very blurry here.

Comment: It could be far more than on Facebook.  In fact I avoid Facebook for  surveys and the sites ask me to log in to them, or to share a post about them on Facebook.  I get the point though. There are some Sundays when I can spend 10 hours on these sometimes, catching up alone.  True though as I've used VPNs that listen to your telephone/conversations.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

*De jure* there are dozens of complex laws and regulations regarding remote employment, under which you may or may not need a special visa in order to work in a given country. Tax laws are an additional complication, where countries such as the UK can deem you as a tax resident for [spending as little as 16 days](https://www.gov.uk/tax-foreign-income/residence) on British soil.

*De facto*, as long as you don't mention your remote job to immigration personnel at the airport, there's a 99.99% chance no one will ever find out. There are millions of people breaking the law by being employed at *on-site* jobs in any given country, so digital nomads are a pretty low priority for law enforcement.